# jprofile issue websphere v6

Tags: jprofiler

I am trying to use Jprofile with WAS v6 running on Linux, followed the setup steps in Jprofile, copied the agent jar to linux box, set up the jvm arguments and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. But seeing this error when I try to startup the server:

JVMCI158: Can't load "libjprofiler.so", because libjprofiler.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
JVMCI098: xmloadJVMHelperLib jprofiler port=8849, failed

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: libjprofiler.so is only for Java 1.4. Are you really profiling a Java 1.4 JVM? Then you have to check if the JVM is 32-bit or 64-bit and that the correct agent library is referenced.